# ProcedureOutputs getCurrent() return NoMoreReturnsException

Tags: hibernate

I have a sql server stored procedure which update a table, and in java I use hibernate to call as follow:

```
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        ProcedureCall call = session2.createStoredProcedureCall("UPDATE_PERSONAL_ADDRESS");
        call.registerParameter( 1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(staffNo);      
        ProcedureOutputs outputs = call.getOutputs();
        do {
            Output output = outputs.getCurrent(); <--NoMoreReturnsException
```

when calling outputs.getCurrent() it throws NoMoreReturnsException, why?
Under what condition will NoMoreReturnsException throws?

part of stack trace is

> 15:16:50,897 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: {call
> UPDATE_PERSONAL_ADDRESS(?)}
>
> 15:32:04,231 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ........
>
> ......
>
> 15:32:04,359 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
>
> 15:32:04,362 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by:
> org.hibernate.result.NoMoreReturnsException: Results have been
> exhausted
>
> 15:32:04,362 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
> deployment.PIM.war//org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.buildOutput(OutputsImpl.java:196)
>
> 15:32:04,485 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
> deployment.PIM.war//org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.getOutput(OutputsImpl.java:171)
>
> 15:32:04,611 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
> deployment.PIM.war//org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.getCurrent(OutputsImpl.java:91)
>
> 15:32:04,612 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
> deployment.PIM.war//com.frw.dao.CustomPersonalHome.syncPersonalAddress(CustomPersonalHome.java:102)
>
> 15:32:04,612 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
> deployment.PIM.war//com.frw.object.repository.PIM904.wb_BTN_38(PIM904.java:285)
>
> 15:32:04,612 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  ... 73 more

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is because the stored procedure does not have any output.
Although in API, it does not mention if the stored procedure has no output. calling ProcedureOutputs.getCurrent() will throws Exception.

API

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/result/Outputs.html#getCurrent()

> Output getCurrent()
>
> Retrieve the current Output object.
>
> Returns:
>
> The current Output object. Can be null